# Retrieve and store checkbox value in database when selected from gridview in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView containing a CheckBox, displaying student attendance information. When I check the CheckBox, the value (which is a bit value) does not get stored in the database.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btn_attendence_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = [CONNECTION STRING];
    cn = new SqlConnection(con);
    cn.Open();
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grid_attendence.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = ((CheckBox)grid_attendence.FindControl("chbox") as CheckBox);
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            st = "insert into atd(attend,stno,stname) values ('" + gvrow.Cells[0].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[1].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[2].Text + "')";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(st, cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Record inserted");
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are only inserting rows that are checked.  So every row that was inserted had been checked.  So, you could always set it to true.

Answer (score 3):

Change `(CheckBox)grid_attendence` by `(CheckBox)gvrow`

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grid_attendence.Rows)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chbox");
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        st = "insert into atd(attend,stno,stname) values ('" + gvrow.Cells[0].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[1].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[2].Text + "')";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(st, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Record inserted");
        cn.Close();

    }
}
```

Some extra things:

- You shouldn't be creating the query like using string concatenation, you're exposed to [`sql injection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) attack. Use parametrized query instead.
- No need to double cast like this `((CheckBox)grid_attendence.FindControl("chbox") as CheckBox)` (take a look to my code)

Answer (score 1):

--Add one more column to your table **status boolean type** and set its value to 0 or 1.

```
CheckBox chk = ((CheckBox)grid_attendence.FindControl("chbox") as CheckBox);
if (chk.Checked)
{
    st = "insert into atd(attend,stno,stname,status) values ('" + gvrow.Cells[0].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[1].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[2].Text + "',1)";
}
else
{
    st = "insert into atd(attend,stno,stname,status) values ('" + gvrow.Cells[0].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[1].Text + "','" + gvrow.Cells[2].Text + "',0)";
}
cmd = new SqlCommand(st, cn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Write("Record inserted");
cn.Close();
```